# How to make RegExp work? (Google Apps Script)

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

Trying write search function that will search for few different formats of numbers (examples: `+############`, `# (###) ###-##-##`, `###########` and etc.  ) and format(replace) in one format (`+7(###)###-##-##`).

*note: format means replace string with string that properly formated, but not use formating setting*

Function. It's right now lacks of replace functionality.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

var history = ss.getSheetByName('sheetname');
ss.setActiveSheet(history);

for(i = 1; i <= history.getMaxRows(); i += 1) {
  var r = history.getRange('D' + i)

  var regexp = RegExp ('/+\d{11}', 'g')

  Logger.log("Value: " + r.getValue())

  if (regexp.exec(r.getValue()) !== null ) {
      Logger.log('true')
    } else {
      Logger.log('false')
    }
}
```

Logger output:

```
Line 1: Value: +#(###)###-##-##
Line 2: false
Line 3: Value: +###########
Line 4: false
Line 5: Value: +###########
Line 6: false
```

`regexp.exec(r.getValue())` returns null.

I except get true on line 4 and 6.

Comment: Can you post sample values/strings that these would be in and their expected outputs?

Comment: Not sure if [this](https://regex101.com/r/rP60OJ/1) is what you're looking for because it's a little unclear

Comment: I got google spreadsheet with values, that constantly changes. So i need format them properly. I'm little bit familiar with regex. I can write manually in search and replace regex and it works, but i wanted to automate this, so it would be like press button and done.

Comment: Does that regex work for you?

Comment: It doesn't work in Google Apps Script enviroment

Comment: It works. The problem was `var regexp = RegExp ('\+?(\d{1,2}?)(?: *\()?(\d{3})(?:\) *)?(\d{3})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{2}\b)', 'g')` But after i wrote `var regexp = /\+?(\d{1,2}?)(?: *\()?(\d{3})(?:\) *)?(\d{3})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{2}\b)/` it was fixed and worked as i wish. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in `var regexp = RegExp ('/+\d{11}', 'g')`. When i wrote `var regexp = /\+\d{11}/` it starts work.

Thank you to [ctwheels](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3600709/ctwheels). He wrote regex which was finding all formats and replaced with right one.

Final solution

```
for(i = 1; i <= history.getMaxRows(); i += 1) {

  var r = history.getRange('D' + i);
  var regexp = /\+?(\d{1,2}?)(?: *\()?(\d{3})(?:\) *)?(\d{3})-?(\d{2})-?(\d{2}\b)/
  var replace = '+7($2)$3-$4-$5';

  if (regexp.exec(r.getValue()) !== null ) {
    var repla = r.getValue().replace(regexp, replace)
    r.setValue(repla)
  }
}
```